# Bootstrap justify toolbar buttons to fill entier rows width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long toolbar with many buttons and that toolbar wraps according to screen width. Is there a way to make each  buttons wrapped in a each row be justified in any way to fill the entire row width.

Here is the current code I am using.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center" role="toolbar">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111111111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111111111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

and some css to make row spacing:

```
.btn-toolbar>.btn, .btn-toolbar>.btn-group, .btn-toolbar>.input-group {
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    /*padding: .2em .3em;*/
}
```

I do not mind using some jquery or other bootstrap components to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Is just giving the buttons a percenage width out of the question or no you could just do something like https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/mnmhsko7/

Comment: No, I do not want to set fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

The working CSS is:

```
.btn-toolbar{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
.btn-toolbar .btn{
    -webkit-box-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-box-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```